# PayPal complete date format

Tags: php

PayPal send back the payment_date field in the following format 19:19:09 Sep 27, 2011

I am using php to calculate days remaining from payment_date, but my code is based on getting the format in 2011-09-27 12:19:00.

How do I change?

This is my code (which works perfectly if date in my correct format):

```
<?php       
$today = time();
$cdate = strtotime('2011-09-27');//strtotime($row_details['payment_date']);// testing
$dateDiff = $today - $cdate;
$fullDays = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));
$dayscalculate = 30 - $fullDays; // Set number of days
echo  $dayscalculate.(($dayscalculate == 1) ? " day" : " days");
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: What's the problem? `strtotime("19:19:09 Sep 27, 2011")` should work just as well as your test value `strtotime('2011-08-21')`

Comment: Perfect.. did not know would just accept that format.. thank you.. put in answer and will accept.. Also is it easy to change the PayPal PST time zone to Australian?? So get the right Australian time etc..

Comment: Ok I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be no issue here.  `strtotime()` will accept PayPal's format as:

```
strtotime("19:19:09 Sep 27, 2011")
```

Just be sure you have the correct timezone set in your php.ini, or at runtime with `date_default_timezone_set()`

Comment: Actually, strtotime will adjust for the timezone specified (PDT in this instance) to convert it to a UTC timestamp, setting the default timezone is useless here.

Comment: @Geoffrey Many PHP installs are distributed with a blank value for `date.timezone` in php.ini, so there is no "default" to fall back on. PHP then issues an `E_WARNING` to the effect of: _PHP Warning:  strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function._  That's why it's mentioned in my answer, in case the OP had not set it.

Comment: ... and the OP asked in the comments how to set the timezone, implying it was not correctly set system-wide.

Comment: This was not a follow up to the OP's question, it was a follow-up to your answer as it makes it appear that the timezone specified on the end of the string (PDT) is ignored by `strtotime`. You should state that it will accept PayPal's format as: `strtotime("19:19:09 Sep 27, 2011 PDT")` which is exactly what PayPal send.

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
$end = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("03:49:26 27 May 2013 PDT"));
echo $end;
?>
```

Result : 2013-05-27 11:49:26