# How to change this date / time into another timezone?

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

We're using PayPal for an order system.

PayPals IPN returns the datestamp in this format:

> 04:47:37 Mar 11, 2015 PDT

I would assume that it will always use PDT for the timezone, but in case this may change I would need to take this into account.

Is this a simple thing to do?

Comment: maybe useful: [strtotime() will accept PayPal's format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577779/paypal-complete-date-format). Also [this date from PayPal IPN - 20:12:59 Jan 13, 2009 PST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874879/php-convert-date-with-datetime-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal will always return date/time in this format  hh:mm:ss MM DD, YYYY ZONE
Check for documentation
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/